# Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Файл functions.php**

```
include __DIR__ . "/mysql.php";
$mysql = new Mysql();   

function checkPassword($pass, $email){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where `email` = :email AND `password` = :password";
    $params = [':email' => $email, ':password' => md5($pass)];
    //var_dump($params);
    var_dump($mysql->query($sql, $params));
}
```

**Функция query из mysql.php**

```
public function query($sql, $params=[])
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($params);
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

**Проверяю функцию в index.php**

```
include(__DIR__. '/core/functions.php');
checkPassword('123123','qwe@mail.ru');
```

И у меня ошибка вот такая выходит.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in 
>   E:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\blackmarket\core\functions.php on line 9

Не могу понять что не так ?! Все переменные не пустые, что ему не нравиться то ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну все дело в области видимости переменных. читаем [доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Что у меня не так с видимостью ? Я передаю значения переменных в параметрах функции, и использую их внутри функции... Что не так то ?

Comment: объект `$mysql` внутрь функции `checkPassword` вы передаете ? Вы хотя бы открыли ссылку что я вам дал ? Там буквально вторым абзацем ваш код разбирают

Comment: Я разобрался спасибо. Ссылку я не увидел сначала...

Answer (score -1):

Объявите все переменные через global внутри функции